# DateField is not rendered as type="date"

Tags: python, tornado, wtforms

```
class Form(Form):
      plan_start = DateField('Plan Start', validators=[Required()])
```

this code will render this html.

```
<input id="plan_start" name="plan_start" type="text" value="">
```

My question is: why the type is `text` and not `date`?

I only can get this resolved by passing explicitly the `type='date'` in template.

```
 {% raw form.plan_start.label %}{% raw form.plan_start(type='date') %}
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use the DateField from html5.

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField


class Form(Form):
    plan_start = DateField('Plan Start', validators=[Required()])
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue.

Comment: ran into this error and this fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanPianka This is the [documented](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#module-wtforms.fields.html5) and the correct way to do it. The `fields.DateField` as being used in the question only renders the text input (see [source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.3.x/wtforms/fields/core.py#L796-L810)). To render a `date` input, you need to use `fields.html5.DateField` as shown in the answer. This will change in version 3 (yet unreleased): DateField will render a date input by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom widget:

```
from django.forms import widgets

class CustomDateInput(widgets.TextInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class Form(Form):
    plan_start = DateField('Plan Start', validators=[Required()], widget=CustomDateInput)
```

Comment: Django? I am not using django.

Answer (score 0):

To get type as date instead of text , you need to pass format option also like below

```
password = DateField('Your Date of Birth', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Not only does this not work, an HTML5 `<input type='date' />` element can't have its format set for it. It depends on the browser, or the OS.