# How to get <input type='month'> working with the django's models.Datefield?

Tags: django, html, forms, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to use the HTML5 month input field for my form and want to store as a models.DateField. My question is this possible? If it is how do I do it? If not why and should I just be using models.CharField?
`

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846048/django-form-as-p-datefield-not-showing-input-type-as-date

Comment: Or a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588393/datefield-is-not-rendered-as-type-date

Comment: I've already created the custom widget and have the form produce a input tag with type = date. But, when I try to submit it. It is not accepted by the Datefield() model. I don't need help getting the making the widget. I need help having it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would just save it as a CharField. To my knowledge, Django doesn't have a way to only save Months, but you can easily simply save the number and work around that